# We're sorry, we encountered an unexpected error. Please refresh the page and try again

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, versioning, save-as-template

When I try to choose a saved template to create a new page, page auto saves which creates multiple duplicates in site page library.
When i click on save as draft it throws error box:
Changes not saved
We're sorry, we encountered an unexpected error. Please refresh the page and try again.

This is happening when i choose saved templates only and under one specific site.

Working by choosing blank template does not give any error.
If i try to save as template from the blank page/template save as template button throws same error as mentioned above.

Comment: Are you trying to save a blank page without header/title as a template?

Comment: I have designed a page with webpart, which has buttons and table of content .
So, when i choose the template by default these things will pop up and after adding page title, title under table of contents, adding in details to the table. during this process, the page keep auto saving multiple times.
When i click on save as draft option, i get error as mentioned above.
If I refresh the page, will get directed to blank template and then it works as normal.

After all this, when i go into site page library, i can see multiple duplicates created.